# Google Analytics does not save date range in custom saved reports

Tags: google-analytics

When I create a custom report in Google Analytics, I can't find a way to save the date range within the report. How is that?

There are several questions regarding how to save/change GA default date range, while apparently, there isn't any solution about this specific problem

Comment: To be clear, you want to set the date range for a specific report, not the default date range when you log in.  Correct?

Comment: Do you want to set it to a specific set of dates (like Jan 1 to Jan 10, 2018) or do you want to set it to relative dates (last 2 months)?

Comment: I'd like to save the report with a given date range, for instance from jan 01 to dec 31

Comment: I would like to do the same thing. This doesn't make any sense for Google. Why would I select a ton of filters and "Save a Report" only to go back and find it is selecting an entirely different date range that has no relevance to any marketing I ran for the parameters I just selected. We need to have the dates saved in the "Saved Report" This is a BUG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question "*How is that?*", it appears Google Analytics (GA) is storing the link data to a custom report in a user only area. The javascript link is stored with some URL parameters as variables so when it is clicked the URL is generated dynamically replacing those with the current state parameter values.

To "fix" the issue GA could add a layer for the user to select which URL parameters need to be codified in the saved link. Then GA would need to add a layer that included sharing options. *Maybe similar to the share object option for dashboards.*
[image: screenshot showing "share object" for a dashboard]

There is a **workaround** I came up with that allows you to both share (or send) a link to the actual report at the current state (including date) and keep up with it in GA. After customizing the report (important: before saving as a custom report) copy the URL. The GA API has built a state reproducible URL for authorized users. You could send this link to whomever and be just be done, but if you want to use GA to document the effort, you can add an annotation there in the report. You need to click the Annotation Drawer dropdown below the explorer.
Pick a date and add add an annotation containing the URL you copied for the report. Because of the character limit (160) you may need to use a URL shortener.

Now feel free to save the report and share the report with the email feature. The share generates a form and has to attach a document of the current state. I choose to go ahead and paste the URL there again. Be sure and send a copy to yourself so you can track the share, otherwise I suppose it goes to the ether.

Answer (score 2):

A method of retaining the date range in a Google Analytics report is to download the report as a PDF, then use the "Go to report" link in the top right corner of the PDF to open the report. The original date range will be respected.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way of doing that, there's no option to save a fixed date range.  You can do it if you use Data  Studio to make your report.